How can I determine if a row in a table is the last one on a page using the OpenPdf library?
I am creating a new document and displaying data in the form of a table. As I populate the table with data, some of the rows formed are subheadings, which must not be the last row on the page. How can I determine, during the table formation process, whether a row will be the last one on the page?
    val directContent = writer.directContent
    val simulation = ColumnText(directContent)
    ...
    val status = simulation.go(true)
    return !ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)
}

However, with this approach, I am unable to determine the current cursor position on the page during the page creation process.
Library version 1.4.2
